# Predict on action button click (shinydashboard)

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

I have developed a shiny web app on the IRIS dataset. I want to make the predictions dynamically. I have 4 input boxes, where the user will input the values and based on the model I want to print the predicted value on screen.

This is my code:
[image: code]

On clicking the 'Predict' action button, it is giving me this output:
[image: output]

I am not able to understand what it means and where I am wrong in my code. I am new to shiny R. Can anybody please help me fix it?

Comment: Try not to put multiple observers inside one another, you might encounter a memory leak

Comment: Thanks @PorkChop for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue!! Posting the answer here in case someone comes across the same issue and looks up for an answer.

The dataframe was not getting populated from the user inputs. Here's how I did it:

```
observeEvent(input$go, {
frames <- cbind(Sepal.Length=as.numeric(input$sl),
Sepal.Width=as.numeric(input$sw),Petal.Length=as. 
numeric(input$pl),Petal.Width=as.numeric(input$pw))
frames <- data.frame(frames)
model <- load(file = "irisn.rda")
dt <- data.frame(Predicted = predict(get(model), frames))
output$predvalue <- renderPrint(dt)
)}
```